# I want to use 'keywords' to help me filter csv data

Tags: python, csv, filter

I have to filter out csv data from given information and print it out. I am new to python and what I had in my head was, I would make keywords in a list, than I would write some function that if it has those words in the csv data it will print out my data.

This is what I tried

```
keywords = ("AIG","Baylor","CGG","Citi","EcconMobil","Flow-Cal Inc.",
       "Global SHop Solutions","Harris Count CTS","HCSS",
       "Hitachi Consulting", "HP Inc.","INT Inc.","JPMorgan Chase & Co",
       "Leidos","McKesson","MRE Consulting Ltd.","NetIQ","PROS",
       "San Jacinto College","SAS","Smartbridge","Sogeti USA",
       "Southwest Research Institute","The Reynolds and Reynolds Company",
       "UH Enterprise Systems","U.S. Marine Corps","ValuD Consuting LLC","Wipro")

pattern = (" ".join(keywords))
with f as filterf:
    for line in filterf:
        if not re.search(pattern,line):
            print(line.strip())

print(pattern)
```

This is what I needed printed out

```
0 AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
1 Baylor College of Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
2 CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
3 Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
4 ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
5 Flow-Cal Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
6 Global Shop Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
7 Harris County CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
8 HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
9 Hitachi Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
10 HP Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
11 INT Inc.,20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
12 JPMorgan Chase & Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
13 Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
14 McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
15 MRE Consulting Ltd.,2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
16 NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
17 PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
18 San Jacinto College ,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
19 SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
20 Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
21 Sogeti USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
22 Southwest Research Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
23 The Reynolds and Reynolds Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
24 UH Enterprise Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
25 U.S. Marine Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
26 ValuD Consuting LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
27 Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
```

and this is my csv data

```
>   ALPHABETICAL ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> ,,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
> Company,Booth,Full-Time,"Full-Time Visa
> Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
> AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
> Baylor�College�of�Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
> CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
> ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,, ,...
> Flow-Cal�Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
> Global�Shop�Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
> Harris�County�CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
> Hitachi�Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
> HP�Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
> INT�Inc.,20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
> JPMorgan�Chase�&�Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
> Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
> McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> MRE�Consulting�Ltd.,2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
> NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,, PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
> San�Jacinto�College��,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
> SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
> Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,, Sogeti�USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
> Southwest�Research�Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> The�Reynolds�and�Reynolds�Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
> UH�Enterprise�Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> U.S.�Marine�Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
> ValuD�Consuting�LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
> Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,, BOOTH ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> ,Booth,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
> Company,#,Full-Time,"Full-Time Visa
> Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
> HP�Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
> "MRE�Consulting,�Ltd.",2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
> JPMorgan�Chase�&�Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
> SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
> ValuD�Consuting�LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
> NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,, Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
> UH�Enterprise�Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,, ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
> Southwest�Research�Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> Hitachi�Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
> San�Jacinto�College��,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
> Sogeti�USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
> "Flow-Cal,�Inc.",16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
> CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
> Global�Shop�Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
> Baylor�College�of�Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
> "INT,�Inc.",20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
> PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
> Harris�County�CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
> The�Reynolds�and�Reynolds�Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
> Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
> U.S.�Marine�Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
> McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,, Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
> HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
> Leidos,30,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
```

I have been looking online and spent so much time reading things. I am brand new, and it's so overwhelming. Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

This is what prints

```
AIG Baylor CGG Citi EcconMobil Flow-Cal Inc. Global SHop Solutions Harris Count CTS HCSS Hitachi Consulting HP Inc. INT Inc. JPMorgan Chase & Co Leidos McKesson MRE Consulting Ltd. NetIQ PROS San Jacinto College SAS Smartbridge Sogeti USA Southwest Research Institute The Reynolds and Reynolds Company UH Enterprise Systems U.S. Marine Corps ValuD Consuting LLC Wipro
```

Comment: How does your current code fail?

Comment: Reduce your input to a single line that should match, a single line that should not match, and two patterns (one that matches one line and one that matches no lines).  Try to go from zero to a full solution all at once is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: Hi! It's not failing it's just not printing like this

'AIG Baylor CGG Citi EcconMobil Flow-Cal Inc. Global SHop Solutions Harris Count CTS HCSS Hitachi Consulting HP Inc. INT Inc. JPMorgan Chase & Co Leidos McKesson MRE Consulting Ltd. NetIQ PROS San Jacinto College SAS Smartbridge Sogeti USA Southwest Research Institute The Reynolds and Reynolds Company UH Enterprise Systems U.S. Marine Corps ValuD Consuting LLC Wipro
'

Comment: Your requirement is that you only want the lines that contain one of the keywords to be printed out and skip others?

Comment: It prints that because you are printing the pattern at the end. That is your pattern value

Comment: @RamkishoreM I would like it to the second block of text I posted. Maybe I shouldn't do keywords and their is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are merely printing your patterns value. The search and print is not printing anything. Try this.

```
with f as filterf:
    output_line_counter = 0
    for line in filterf:
        if any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
            print(output_line_counter, line.strip())
            output_line_counter += 1
```

Remove the `print(pattern)` line after this

Comment: Wow you guys are so helpful, thank you so much. Now to figure out how to remove the spaces between them. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you mean there is an empty line between 2 lines of text? if that is the case, remove `print()`

Comment: Haha yeah that's all it took! Thank you :) I can finally move on to the next part.

Comment: The only thing I am wondering is that the numbers left of the keywords aren't showing. Seen from my 2nd block of text I posted, it shows the numbers the left since I am guessing those are rows from the cvs file. Any input on that?

Comment: you have to do add line numbers manually. Check modified answer